Filter an array of objects with multiple keys of arrays
I have an array of objects
const Data = [
  {first_name: 'Ammy', city_name: 'LA', age: 22, designation: 'officer'},
  {first_name: 'Dave', city_name: 'Paris', age: 23, designation: 'engineer'},
  {first_name: 'Cindy', city_name: 'Tokyo', age: 32, designation: 'influencer'},
  {first_name: 'Barn', city_name: 'sydney', age: 34, designation: 'lawyer'},
  {first_name: 'Yolanda', city_name: 'Seoul', age: 32, designation: 'chef'},
  {first_name: 'Mike', city_name: 'London', age: 42, designation: 'bartender'},
  {first_name: 'Olivia', city_name: 'LA', age: 34, designation: 'officer'}
]

I also have an object containing filters
const Filters = {
  first_name: ['Ammy', 'Dave', 'Mike'],
  city_name: ['LA'],
  age: [22, 34]
}

I have to filter the data so that all the filters are applied and it should be an and condition. For the above Data and Filters only the row containing Ammy should be displayed. The challenging part is that the filters can have only one key or all keys. Filters can be just { first_name: ['Dave']}
I tried writing some code but it will not apply all the filters
const newData = []; 
Object.entries(Filters).map(([filter, Values]) => {
  const filteredData = Data.filter(item => {
    if (Values.find( value => value === item[filter])) {
      newData.push(item); 
    } 
  });  
}) 


You're approaching it the wrong way around. You want to filter your data, so Data.filter should be what it starts with. And then inside your callback function, you loop over your Filters, to check if they apply, one by one. If they all apply, then your return true, otherwise false.

Thank you for the suggestion it seems like my approach was indeed the other way around, i need to work more on array operations.

Mapping the Object.entries() of filters won't get you your desired result, you need to filter() your data array.
What you can do is for each object in data (ie: person), check if every key from filters has value from its array as a value in the current person object you're looking at (using .some()). If it does, then you can return true keeping the object in the final array:


const data = [{ first_name: 'Ammy', city_name: 'LA', age: 22, designation: 'officer' }, { first_name: 'Dave', city_name: 'Paris', age: 23, designation: 'engineer' }, { first_name: 'Cindy', city_name: 'Tokyo', age: 32, designation: 'influencer' }, { first_name: 'Barn', city_name: 'sydney', age: 34, designation: 'lawyer' }, { first_name: 'Yolanda', city_name: 'Seoul', age: 32, designation: 'chef' }, { first_name: 'Mike', city_name: 'London', age: 42, designation: 'bartender' }, { first_name: 'Olivia', city_name: 'LA', age: 34, designation: 'officer' } ];
const filters = { first_name: ['Ammy', 'Dave', 'Mike'], city_name: ['LA'], age: [22, 34] };

const filterEntires = Object.entries(filters);
const res = data.filter(person => filterEntires.every(
  ([key, values]) => values.some(val => val === person[key])
));
console.log(res);




@lucky if this answers your question consider marking it as answered by clicking the grey checkmark in the top left of the answer
